# Flutter-Web: Tips/Tools for debugging web?

Tags: debugging, flutter-web

**Let me clear that I understand why I'm getting this error, the web doesn't have a file system, so I can't use `getApplictionSupportDocumentsDirectory()`. I'm not, but apparently some plugin is.**

*This is only an example error, I'm not really asking for help resolving this exact one.*

Sometimes, like here, the error in Android Studio is absolutely not helpful. None of the stack trace references any of my files. Chrome's developer log is identical, but the stack trace doesn't go as deep.

```
Error: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getApplicationSupportDirectory on channel plugins.flutter.io/path_provider)
    at Object.throw_ [as throw] (http://localhost:12684/dart_sdk.js:5067:11)
    at MethodChannel._invokeMethod (http://localhost:12684/packages/flutter/src/services/restoration.dart.lib.js:1560:21)
    at _invokeMethod.next (<anonymous>)
    at http://localhost:12684/dart_sdk.js:40571:33
    at _RootZone.runUnary (http://localhost:12684/dart_sdk.js:40441:59)
    at _FutureListener.thenAwait.handleValue (http://localhost:12684/dart_sdk.js:35363:29)
    at handleValueCallback (http://localhost:12684/dart_sdk.js:35931:49)
    at Function._propagateToListeners (http://localhost:12684/dart_sdk.js:35969:17)
    at _Future.new.[_completeWithValue] (http://localhost:12684/dart_sdk.js:35817:23)
    at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (http://localhost:12684/dart_sdk.js:35838:35)
    at Object._microtaskLoop (http://localhost:12684/dart_sdk.js:40708:13)
    at _startMicrotaskLoop (http://localhost:12684/dart_sdk.js:40714:13)
    at http://localhost:12684/dart_sdk.js:36191:9
```

I've run into this issue a few times, where the stack trace isn't useful for debugging the problem.

Are there any tools/tips available to help with this?